# angular - jasmine : Cant test method because of spy

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a some concrete methods in my component:

```
public show(summary: GridSummary) {
    this.resetModal(summary);
    this.summary.direction = this.summary.direction || 'Response';
    this.title = this.getTitle(summary);
    this.parentId = this.summary.id;
    this.parentType = 'Dcc' + this.summary.direction;
    this.openModal(this.dialog);
    this.auditService.getAudits(this.summary.pipelineId).subscribe(
      (summaries) => { this.populateTabs(summaries); },
      (error) => this.showSubmitError(error));
  }

 public hasSummaries(): boolean {
    return this.auditSummaries && this.auditSummaries.length > 0;
  }

 private populateTabs(summaries: AuditSummary[]) {
    this.auditSummaries = summaries;
    if (this.isFailed()) {
      if (this.isDtcFlow() || this.isDataExport()) {
        this.getErrorDetails();
      } else {
        this.getComments(false);
      }
    } else {
      if (this.isRequest()) {
        this.getComments(false);
      }
      this.dataReady = true;
    }
  }
```

The auditSummaries gets set from the show method.

So in my spec file I place a spy on my show method.

setting:

```
showSpy = spyOn(comp, 'show');
```

in my before each. Then in my 'it' test:

```
it('Show shows the model', async(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(showSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      }));
```

This test is fine. The issue I have is trying to test that hasSummaries has been set with :

```
it('hasSummaries return true after show', async(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
          expect(comp.hasSummaries()).toBe(true);
        });
      }));
```

because I'm using a spy on the main method, then the audit service doesn't really get called. So I cannot test hasSummaries in the above way. How can I test this.

I'm using Angular 9, Jasmine 3.5, Karma 4.4

Comment: `The auditSummaries gets set from the show method` . I dont see it being set in `show()` . Let me know if I am missing something

Comment: @ShashankVivek There is a call `this.populateTabs(summaries)` it's that that populates my auditSummaries. The populateTabs method only gets called from the  show method.

Comment: Can you show that method as well ? because its  a direct dependency on what you are testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to spy on a function and preserve the original behavior, you need to use [callThrough](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E).

From the doc:

> By chaining the spy with and.callThrough, the spy will still track all
>   calls to it but in addition it will delegate to the actual
>   implementation.

In your case, you will want to do:

```
spyOn(comp, 'show').and.callThrough()
```